# Pandas: Update certain column values based on same column value but different rows and condition

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Python 3.6 and Pandas 0.25.

I have following dataframe:

```
import collections
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    'col1_data': ['A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A2', 'A2'],
    'col2_data': ['UNMAPPED', 'UNMAPPED', 'GOOD VALUE', 'UNMAPPED', 'CORRECT VALUE']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

It looks like below:

```
display(df)
```

[image: Before Data]

Basically I want to update "col2_data" values to "Good Value" for all "A1"s in col1_data and "Correct Value" for all "A2"s in col1_data.

Basically I want the dataframe to look like:

[image: After Data]

Basically, I need to do data update based on group (col1_data value) but no aggregation i.e. I do not want to reduce the number of rows.
So if there are 3 rows with same value(A1), all three rows should have same value in col2_data (GOOD VALUE) or which is not equal to "UNMAPPED".

Can someone please help here?

**UPDATE 1:**
The UNMAPPED value does not come on come in any fixed sequence.
The solution from Scot works well for 2 columns of DF. However, the DF has multiple columns (which are not required for grouping or check); grouping is dependent only on col1_data. How do we retain other columns as well in DF?

e.g.

```
data = {
    'col1_data': ['A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A2', 'A2'],
    'col2_data': ['UNMAPPED', 'UNMAPPED', 'GOOD VALUE', 'UNMAPPED', 'CORRECT VALUE'],
    'col3_data': ['B1', 'B2', 'B1', 'B3', 'B4']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image: New Input]

Expected output:

[image: Expected output]

Also, if it is easier to add new derived column based on above logic, it is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the "correct" string is always the last in a group, then you can replace or mask, "UNMAPPED" with np.nan and bfill.

```
df.replace('UNMAPPED', np.nan).bfill()
```

Output:

```
  col1_data      col2_data
0        A1     GOOD VALUE
1        A1     GOOD VALUE
2        A1     GOOD VALUE
3        A2  CORRECT VALUE
4        A2  CORRECT VALUE
```

Which works in this case.  Or, if it is the first in the group then you can use `ffill()`

If it appears anywhere in the group, then you can use:

```
df['col2_data'] = df[['col2_data']].replace('UNMAPPED', np.nan).groupby('col1_data')['col2_data']\
  .transform(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
```

Comment: Thanks @Scott Boston. The last one worked well for me.
However, the above was sample. My dataframe has multiple columns. However, the group criteria is only col1_data (other cols does not matter for group or value) but other values should remain as-is. I have updated my question, how to retain the other columns in df?